# how can I modify the copy and other menus that appear when long-pressed in wkwebview?

Tags: menu, wkwebview, ios16, long-press

**In iOS 16**, when loading HTML with WKWebView, how can I modify the copy and other menus that appear when long-pressed? I want to add a custom menu.

like this:
[image]

I have tried various methods that I could find, but none of them seem to work well on **iOS 16**.